# LINQ Let operator with lambda syntax

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

I know that there is let operator in linq query syntax. It is useful to store the result of a sub-expression in order to use it in subsequent clauses.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/let-clause

But I prefer work with linq lambda syntax. When I work with a lot of joins i get chain of objects (which represent each level of joins ie: `

```
s.secondJoin.firstJoin.dd.DataType`
```

I would like to set some sub result in variable and use it for more convinient work in the following ie:

`let joinResult = s.secondJoin.firstJoin` and after
`joinResult.dd.DataType`

**Q:** Is it possible in linq lambda syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Equivalent to `let` in lambda syntax is `Select` to create an anonymous type, for example:

```
items.Select(s => new
{
    s = s,
    joinResult = s.secondJoin.firstJoin
})
```

After this you can use both `s` and `joinResult` as you could with `let` in query syntax.

Comment: It's probably worth changing "tuple" to "anonymous types" to avoid confusion, particularly now that C# *does* have built-in support for tuples... which *aren't* supported in expression trees.